# understanding group closure

Tags: group-theory

As we know from the group axioms,for all elements a, b in G, a*b is in G.
I am just wondering if a=b, wether or not a*b is still in G.

I am trying to prove that
the set (1, 2, . . . , p − 1) of p − 1 integers under multiplication modulo p is not a group, where p is not prime.
When considering the closure, my professor chose p = 4, and wrote 2·2 mod 4 as the counter example. 2 and 2 are the same, so I am not sure why they used the same elements here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If $ab$ is in $G$ for all $a$ and $b$ in $G$, then of course this includes the case $a=b$. "For all" really means for all elements $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Closure of a group $(G,*)$ says that for any two elements $a, b \in G$, $a*b$ is also in $G$. There's nothing wrong with taking $a=b$. Indeed, closure demands that for any $a \in G$, $a*a=a^2 \in G$.

Here, taking $a=2$, for closure we require that $2 * 2 = 4 \in G$, which is not true. We only need to find *one* counterexample to show that closure does not hold. If we were trying to prove closure instead, we would have to show it is true for *any* $a,b \in G$, and then we could not assume that $a=b$.

Comment: thank you ! understand now